# Results of SAMPLE clause using a DBlink between 2 Oracle databases not randomised

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dblink

I'm using the SAMPLE clause to retrieve random rows from a table. It works fine except when the table is from another database. I'm using a database link between 2 Oracle 11g databases (11.2).

This query returns different random rows everytime I run it:

```
select * from myTable sample(10);
```

But this one always returns the same rows and in the same order:

```
select * from myTable@myDbLink sample(10);
```

I expected at least the same behavior as the tables are on the same version of Oracle. Why isn't it working? Is there a specific way to write this query so it can work with the link?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oracle documentation for the `SELECT ... SAMPLE` clause, the sample is **random**; it is just a coincidence that you are always getting the same rows on the local machine.  You could try adding the SEED(x) clause, where x is a number from 0 to 4294967295; but that may not help going across a database link.

```
select * from myTable@myDbLink sample(10) seed(42);
```

Per the Oracle documentation:

> SEED seed_value Specify this clause to instruct the database **to attempt to** return the
>   same sample from one execution to the next. The seed_value must be an integer
>   between 0 and 4294967295. If you omit this clause, then the resulting sample will
>   change from one execution to the next.

Notice it is still not guaranteed!

Comment: It seems you didn't understand. I'm getting the same rows on the distant machine, not the local one. And using seed is just the opposite of what I want; I want randomness.

Comment: Hmmmm. Interesting.  Different operating systems on the two machines, or perhaps different versions/patches of the operating systems?

Comment: No, the DBlink is between 2 Oracle instances on the same OS, CentOS 5.6

Comment: Only thing I can think of is maybe the patch levels are not exactly the same, or the environment variables for the `oracle` user id such as the `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` aren't the same, so the randomizing is differing.  You may want to try setting the seed to a random number on the remote machine, such as using the `dbms_random.value(1, 1024)` like this:

`select * from myTable@myDbLink sample(10) seed(dbms_random.value(1, 1024));`